# ImageMagick not letting me upload jpgs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I am running Paperclip 2.3.11 and ImageMagick 6.7.1-1.
I am uploading images to an Amazon S3 account.

If I upload a `.png` file it works fine, if I upload a `.jpg` it does not.

This is the error generated in my view when I try uploading a jpg:

```
3 errors prohibited this post from being saved:
  Photo /var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/stream20110817-6147-urdz8d-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
  Photo /var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/stream20110817-6147-urdz8d-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
  Photo /var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/stream20110817-6147-urdz8d-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

And my log reads:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 17 20:35:12 -0400 2011
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Post", "post"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10c64d900 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[photo]\"; filename=\"Stonehenge.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="Stonehenge.jpg", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/RackMultipart20110817-6147-1uad809-0>>, "title"=>"test", "description"=>"test"}, "authenticity_token"=>"V/EinZAi2NNYx7AokikTpQFkNtADNiauW5vcNGdhTug=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"}
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/stream20110817-6147-urdz8d-0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/k9/kw7hkdmx741cqrc1h6_qwc580000gp/T/stream20110817-6147-urdz8d-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Let me know if any other info would be helpful.

UPDATE:
Just noticed that .jpg files **do** upload fine on a different computer (both are Macs running 10.6/10.7 respectively). This leaves me even more lost. What could be misconfigured on my other machine?

Comment: Have you set which file types to allow via the paperclip configs?

Comment: What happen if you copy the file to the system and run `identify -format %wx%h your_file.jpg`?

Comment: This is the result I get when I do that: `identify: no decode delegate for this image format `1100.jpeg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install JPG support for ImageMagick.

> http://www.randycullom.com/chatterbox/archives/2006/12/installing_imag.html

Here is jpegsrc and other sources for ImageMagick:

> http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/

Comment: Hm, this seemed like the right answer, though following it is a bit over my head, I went ahead and picked through parts of it. But at the end of the tutorial there is a test to see if everything works and my system passed the test for each file type... So I'm guessing the problem lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this fixed. Based on @floor's answer. ImageMagick did not have jpg support on this machine. I had to uninstall and reinstall, then uninstall and reinstall Rmagick as well. Everything is working now.

Comment: This particular article was very helpful. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=3ql54he3mrpimvhh093uljjo23#unix